# Не работает тема в neovim

Tags: vim

Не могу никак завести тему gruvbox в nvim.
Использую терминал urxvt.
Вот фото
[image: Фото neovim]

Код где я думаю есть ошибка :

```
"dein Scripts-----------------------------

if &compatible

  set nocompatible               " Be iMproved

endif

" Required:

set runtimepath+=/home/user/.config/nvim/repos/github.com/Shougo/dein.vim

" Required:

if dein#load_state('/home/user/.config/nvim')

  call dein#begin('/home/user/.config/nvim')


  " Let dein manage dein

  " Required:

  call dein#add('/home/user/.config/nvim/repos/github.com/Shougo/dein.vim')

  " Add or remove your plugins here:

    call dein#add('Shougo/neosnippet.vim')

  call dein#add('Shougo/neosnippet-snippets')

  call dein#add('scrooloose/nerdtree')

  " You can specify revision/branch/tag.

  call dein#add('Shougo/vimshell', { 'rev': '3787e5' })

  call dein#add('jiangmiao/auto-pairs')

  call dein#add('shougo/denite.nvim')

  call dein#add('vim-airline/vim-airline')

  call dein#add('vim-airline/vim-airline-themes')

  call dein#add('chriskempson/base16-vim')

  call dein#add('morhetz/gruvbox')

  call dein#add('roxma/nvim-completion-manager')

  call dein#add('kien/ctrlp.vim')

  " Required:

  call dein#end()

  call dein#save_state()

endif

" Required:

filetype plugin indent on

syntax on

" If you want to install not installed plugins on startup.

"if dein#check_install()

"  call dein#install()

"endif

set enc=utf8

"End dein Scripts-------------------------

set t_Co=256

colorscheme gruvbox

set background=dark

map <F8> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"

inoremap <expr> <S-Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<S-Tab>"

set shortmess+=c

let g:airline_theme='base16_google'

let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
```

Comment: Изображение вашего кода не помогает. Не могли бы вы разместить его в текстовом формате, чтобы мы могли помочь вам лучше?

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Сразу говорю, что set t_Co=256 не сработало

Comment: самое первое - отключить конфиг и применить только тему. Если она отображается корректно, то включать потихоньку куски конфига.

Comment: Тема работает глючно, проверял

Comment: Я тут прочитал про поддержку 256 цветов в urxvt

Comment: Но чего-то не работает

Comment: Так как на xfce terminal работает нормально, а на urxvt нет

Comment: То есть, подсуммируем - не работает в urxvt тема, а конфиг не при чем.

Comment: Не, цвета в шелле работают, но в vim и nvim нет